# Не работает удаление строки таблицы

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap, javascript

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на div c id `#delete_row` удалялась строка с подставленным data атрибутом в этом же div`e.

Вот код на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6v2us3e/1/).

Еще по возможности, кто сможет сделать так, чтобы для каждого вопроса можно было добавлять и удалять правильные и неправильные ответы, как у 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дайте диву класс и функционал, который будет искать внутри себя нужный дата атрибут и удалять элемент с ним:

**html:**

```
<div data-action-del="hello">
    <div data-target-del="hello">Delete me</div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
var $actionDel = $('[data-action-del]');
$actionDel.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    var thisTarget = $this.attr('data-action-del');
    var $thisTarget = $this.find('[data-target-del="'+thisTarget+'"]');
    if ($thisTarget.length) { $thisTarget.remove(); }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uq2hwd3o/

P.S. Не пользуйтесь "айдишниками" для таких вещей, т.к. рано или поздно вы столкнётесь с ограничением того, что #ID может быть в единственным экземпляре на странице. Лучше используется специальные "нестилизованные" классы, типа: `.js-action-name` или дата-атрибуты.